# how read lines file with two columns in random choice function

Tags: python, random

I have a file, which consists of two columns. I do not know how I can use it in `random.choice`/`sample` to randomly choose a word from the first column.

How can I get only the first column if I want to random words only?

```
random.choice(open(file).readlines())
```

Is this the correct way?

```
i     A
am    B
well  C
.
what  W
about Y
you   Z
?
she   M
is    N
dreaming O
.
```

Comment: The code you have shown selects a random line out of a file. What is the problem with that? Yes, `random.sample` and `random.choice` are not the same.

Comment: You can call `.split()[0]` on the whole line to get just the first column: `random.choice(open(file).readlines()).split()[0]`

Comment: @mkrieger1 problem is that I get ```['am\t\B\n']``` while using ```random.sample(lines,1)``` and ```am B``` in random,choice. As I mentioned I do not want the 2nd column.

Comment: @JohnGordon I tried your method ,it says ```AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'``` ```random.choice((open(file).readlines()).split()[0])``` when I put bracket around it. any idea why is it ? also how to do it with ```random.sample(...,1)```

Comment: `random.sample` returns a list of length 1 if you ask for 1 item.  Just use [0] on that before splitting.